# How to display a greet message include text and image in nodejs

Tags: node.js, facebook, bots, facebook-messenger, messenger

I want to show greeting message when user start a conversation on Facebook messenger before user input any message.

I did code in node js server that only triggers when user sends a message but I want to show greeting message like below.

[image]

I want to know where I should code for welcome message. I read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/greeting-text but here only text is possible.

This link also for text greeting [Facebook Messenger :How to show a greeting message when start conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37874184/facebook-messenger-how-to-show-a-greeting-message-when-start-conversation)

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for "Get Started" [1]? You should probably configure your chat thread to display such a button, and listen for the callback from the Get Started button. Then send your card (with image) upon the webhook call is received.

[1] https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button

Comment: Thanks @AndrewB I am not getting "Get Started", I have enabled it in settings of page settings & followed all steps of here http://stackoverflow.com/a/36754730/1741671 . Could you please help ?

Comment: Hm, @Williams. I didn't change anything in the settings to include the Get Started button, I simply send the data structure they propose on the previous link I sent under "Examples".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using nodejs, use **request** (or curl) to create the Greeting button and pass a parameter to listen on the post back.

```
let request = require('request');

request.post({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=${ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    qs: {
        setting_type: 'call_to_actions',
        thread_state: 'new_thread',
            call_to_actions: [{
                payload: 'GET_START'
            }]
        },
    json: true
}, (err, res, body) => {
    // Deal with the response
});
```

After that, you can listen for a post back called 'GET_START' and return a welcome message.

```
request({
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: {
        access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
    },
    json: {
        recipient: {
            id: SENDER_ID
        },
        message: {
            attachment: {
                type: "template",
                payload: {
                    template_type: "generic",
                    elements: {
                        "title": "Your Title",
                        "subtitle": "Welcome to my messenger bot",
                        "image_url": "https://mybot.example.com/images/logo.jpg"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, (err, res, body) => {
    // Deal with the response
});
```

Comment: This won't work. The title will be sent as the message.

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't send text and an image in the same message as far as I'm aware.

The closest you can get to what you want is to use the generic template. The only issue is that you would need to make use of a button.